# Websocket connection through front-end or back-end

Tags: angularjs, django, websocket

am developing a single page for monitoring purpose , some of data in this page come through a websocket as a realtime monitoring , and other data fetched from the database as a historical report .

[image]

**My Question :**
 
Should i  establish the websocket connection in the backend and then send the data to the connected client OR just connect to the websocket server in client side .

*Note:*
 - no need to save the messages come from the webscoket server.
Please i need details .

Thanks

Comment: Connecting directly might be simpilest , most of the popular web servers used to host django are not optimized at having many long standing open connections

Comment: Thanks for the answer , am looking for much details regarding to performance , security .